# Removing the path from a GetFiles return

Tags: c#

I am attempting to simply for this bit create a list of the songs within the MyMusic folder and display them in a listbox. The strings will also be used later for voice commands but adding those will not be a problem. My problem is that despite my attempts, I have been unable to remove the path from the displayed name.

```
InitializeComponent();
        string path = @"C:\Users\Toby\Music";
        string[] Songs = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        List<string> SongList = new List<string>();
        int pathlngth = path.Length;
        int i = 0;
        string fix; 
        foreach (string Asong in Songs)
        {
           fix = Asong.Remove(0,pathlngth);
           fix = Asong.Remove(Asong.Length-4);
           SongList.Add(fix);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        SongList.Add("");
        SongList.Add("There are " + i + " songs");
        SongBox.Datasource = SongList;
```

To me at least, this should work. However the results from my Listbox will appear as so:

- C:\Users\Toby\Music\Across the line
- C:\Users\Toby\Music\Behind Closed Doors

And so on...
Any idea what's wrong? I managed to finally remove the extension. I have tried replacing pathlngth with path.Length to no change at all.

Comment: [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In order to get just the filename from a full file path, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpathstring)`. If you don't want the extension either, use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` instead.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you want [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Now I just feel silly...But that is perfect thank you, I don't suppose you happen to know why mine isn't working though do you? I'll certainly use that, I need the full path on a different form for actually playing the song but the name is perfect for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get **FileName** from a path

```
string strSongName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileFullPath);
```

To get **FileNameWithoutExtension** from a path

```
string sFileNameWithOutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileFullPath);
```

Your Solution:

```
List<string> SongList = new List<string>();
string path = @"C:\Users\Toby\Music";
string[] Songs = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

SongList.Add("");
SongList.Add("There are " + Songs.Length + " songs");

foreach (string Asong in Songs)
{
    string sFileNameWithOutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Asong);
    SongList.Add(sFileNameWithOutExtension);
}

SongBox.DataSource = SongList;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an API that already does exactly that - [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (string song in Songs)
{
    SongList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(song));
}
```

This will give you the name + extension, if you want to omit the extension you can use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of "fix" and then immediately overwriting it.

```
fix = Asong.Remove(0,pathlngth);
fix = Asong.Remove(Asong.Length-4);
```

Should probably be

```
fix = Asong.Remove(0,pathlngth);
fix = fix.Remove(Asong.Length-4);
```

The other option is to just use Path.GetFileName(Asong); but you'll still need to manipulate it to remove the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you care for saving the path and just don't want to display it, than any of the previous solutions will be good for you.

If you only care of of the file names than the following will be just for you.

```
var resultFileNames = Songs.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s));
```

This will produce a new list based on Songs but will only store their file names.